# Get the column value of the ngTable directive

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I'm using [ngTable](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1) directive as my grid.So I need to capture the row's text box value change without using any button (Please see the image below).How can I use `$watch` or other method to do that ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

**html**

```
<table class="table" ng-table="UnitsParams" template-pagination="custom/pager">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in Event.UnitsDetails">
    <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'FirstName'">{{item.FirstName}} {{item.LastName}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Email'"><a href="mailTo:{{item.Email}}">{{item.Email}}</a></td>
    <td data-title="'Units'"><input type="number" ng-model="item.Units" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ng-blur` in your textbox

Something like

```
<td data-title="'Units'"><input type="number" ng-blur="getValue(item)" ng-model="item.Units" /></td>
```

javascript code looks like in your controller

```
$scope.getValue=function(item)
{
alert(item.Units)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend :).I have used `ng-change()`.